# Apache doesn't find Python module

Tags: python, apache, opencv

I am trying to run a python script in apache and it works if I use default libraries, but when I try to import a module a installed, it doesn't find it. It's working if I run the script from console, but when I run it from the web server, it says that it can't find the script.

I am using raw cgi for python scripts.

This is my httpd.conf :

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

The library I'm importing is OpenCV (cv2).

This is the error :

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0) 
      args = ('/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_...required by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0)',) 
      message = '/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_...required by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0)'
```

I am guessing that I have to somehow install the C++ libraries on Apache, but I have no idea how or if that's the issue.

**EDIT**

I did a `strings libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIB` and got this result:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
```

How can I get the 3.4.9 version?

Comment: not related to your problem, but using the 3.0(dev) opencv version might be a bad idea. if you run into weird problems(apart from the curent), do a `git checkout 2.4`, and rerun cmake, to get the stable 2.4.9 version (the master branch is (unfortunately) the default for the github src)

Comment: I am intentionally using the 3.0 version because the older ones didn't have some functions that I needed.

Comment: ah, ok. ignore me then. (just happens to a lot of folks unintentionally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix this, but it's not a pretty one.

I copied the libstdc++.so.6.0.19 from my /usr/lib and copied it into /opt/lampp/lib and relinked the libstdc++.so.6 to the new file. It was linked to libstdc++.so.6.0.8 previously.

I didn't find any other "legit" way of doing this.